# Win 10 desktop pc slow to boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, performance

Since installing Fall Creators Win 10 final release after various Insider releases, I find my PC takes a couple of minutes to boot from power on. The hardware is the same but earlier Win 10's were a lot faster.

My specs are here http://speccy.piriform.com/results/EVFBXGdtOpGZlZ47GkUfh3T

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the system with Clean Boot, if Clean Boot model is faster than normal boot, please narrow down the problem via re-enabling boot item one by one.

**Perform a clean startup to determine whether background programs are interfering with your game or program**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/331796/perform-a-clean-startup-to-determine-whether-background-programs-are-i

Besides, check/install available update/hotfix using system built-in Windows Update, as Fall Creators Update has been installed,  OS Build 16299.125 is the newest until now.

**December 12, 2017—KB4054517 (OS Build 16299.125)**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054517